# How can I update Customer Status when the last invoice for that customer is more than 24 months old

Tags: netsuite

I want to set up a scheduled script or a workflow in NetSuite that will automatically change the customer status from "Customer-Closed Won" to "Customer-Closed Lost" if their last invoice is more than 2 years old.

Is this possible with the normal workflow setup or do I need to use a bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to create a scheduled script that runs at some interval - say every Sunday morning. This script can call a saved search that looks at all invoices grouped by customer and max invoice date. The customer status of "customer-closed won" could be a criterion so that you don't look at the ones you already set to "lost". The script can then update all such customer to the "lost" status.

You will also want to write a workflow or user-event on a SO so that if such a "lost" customer creates a new Sales Order, you reset their status to "won"

Comment: Worked like a charm. The only issue I'm running into now is a company policy, I cannot set a child account to lost unless the parent company and all child companies are all inactive(in this case no invoices for 2 years). Is there some way I could work around that?

Comment: Great! A workaround could be to introduce a special attribute. Say a checkbox called 'vanished', that the above scripts/workflows can set/unset in addition to the status.  Also, try/catch the code that sets the status and suppress the exception thrown due to the company policy to keep the code working clean.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is with a pair of workflows.

One workflow triggers on a schedule and uses a saved search that identifies customer-closed-won where the last invoice (and sales order?) was earlier than your cutoff. It has just a single action that resets the customer status.

The other is a workflow on sales that sets the customer status back to customer-closed-won when a Sales Order is approved (or an invoice is created). This also has a single action that changes the status.

If you don't have workflows available under customization go to Setup > Company > Enable Features. Click SuiteCloud and enable SuiteFlow